# Firefox browser crashing Marionette error gecko selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, gecko

Selenium 3.141.59
Gecko driver v26
Java 11.0.4
Seeing issue 2 out of 5 runs
Immediately FF will crash witherror attached screen shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GTC.jpg)